# Jetstream profile photo bigger 1M

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I try to upload photo with Jetstream livewire bigger than 1M and always return failed to upload photo, I increse the size in UpdateUserProfileInformation and the upload_max_filesize in php.in but always return the same.

```
<?php

class UpdateUserProfileInformation implements UpdatesUserProfileInformation
{
    /**
     * Validate and update the given user's profile information.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($user, array $input)
    {
        Validator::make(
            $input,
            [
                "name" => ["required", "string", "max:255"],
                "email" => [
                    "required",
                    "email",
                    "max:255",
                    Rule::unique("users")->ignore($user->id),
                ],
                "photo" => ["nullable", "mimes:jpg,jpeg,png", "max:20000"],
                "birthday" => ["required", "date", "before:-18 years"],
                "phone" => [
                    "required",
                    Rule::unique("users")->ignore($user->id),
                    'regex:/^\+?[0-9]{8,15}$/',
                ],
            ],
            ["birthday.before" => "Debe ser mayor de edad"]
        )->validateWithBag("updateProfileInformation");

        if (isset($input["photo"])) {
            $user->updateProfilePhoto($input["photo"]);
        }

        if (
            $input["email"] !== $user->email &&
            $user instanceof MustVerifyEmail
        ) {
            $this->updateVerifiedUser($user, $input);
        } else {
            $user
                ->forceFill([
                    "name" => $input["name"],
                    "email" => $input["email"],
                    "birthday" => $input["birthday"],
                    "phone" => $input["phone"],
                ])
                ->save();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the nginx config file, I had to put the following bit in my default.conf

```
    server { 
    ....
    client_max_body_size 12M;
    ...
    }
```